# Using Pandas with XLSB File

Tags: python, pandas, xlsb

Trying to read a xlsb file to create a DF in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

a_data = pd.ExcelFile(
    r'C:\\Desktop\\a.xlsb')

df_data = pd.read_excel(a_data, 'Sheet1', engine='pyxlsb')
print(df.head())
```

When I run the script I keep getting this error.

OSError: File contains no valid workbook part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pyxlsb`, all latest version of pandas support this.
Use following code:

```
import pandas as pd
a_data = pd.ExcelFile(r'C:\\Desktop\\a.xlsb')
df = pd.read_excel('a_data', sheet_name='Sheet1', engine='pyxlsb')
```

You will have to install `pyxlsb`first using command: `pip install pyxlsb`